# FPTAN Example x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

According to Intel documentation, this is what `FPTAN` does:

> Replace ST(0) with its approximate tangent and push 1 onto the FPU stack.

And this is a code I wrote in NASM:

```
section .data
    fVal: dd 4
    fSt0: dq 0.0
    fSt1: dq 0.0

section .text
    fldpi
    fdiv  dword[fVal]  ; divide pi by 4 and store result in ST(0).
    fptan
    fstp  qword[fSt0]  ; store ST(0)
    fstp  qword[fSt1]  ; store ST(1)
```

At this point the values of `fSt0` and `fSt1`, I find are:

`fSt0 = 5.60479e+044`
`fSt1 = -1.#IND`

But, shouldn't `fSt0` and `fSt1` be both `1`?

Comment: Why `dd 4` (integer) and not `dd 4.0` (a float)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank's, it worked, the details war, never ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael Petch has already pointed out in a comment, you have a simple typo. Instead of declaring `fVal` as a floating-point value (as intended), you declared it as a 32-bit integer. Change:

```
fVal: dd 4
```

to:

```
fVal: dd 4.0
```

Then your code will work as intended. It is correctly written.

If you *wanted* to take an integer input, you could do it by changing your code to use the `FIDIV` instruction. This instruction will first convert an integer to a double-precision floating-point value, and then do the divide:

```
fldpi
fidiv  dword [fVal]    ; st(0) = pi / fVal
fptan                  ; st(0) = tan(st(0))
                       ; st(1) = 1.0
fstp   qword [fSt0]
fstp   qword [fSt1]
```

But because the conversion is required, this is slightly less efficient than if you had just given the input as a floating-point value.

Note that, if you were going to do this, it would be more efficient on certain older CPUs to break up the load so that it was done separately from the division—*e.g.*,

```
fldpi
fild   dword [fVal]
fdivp  st(1), st(0)    ; st(0) = pi / fVal
fptan                  ; st(0) = tan(st(0))
                       ; st(1) = 1.0
fstp   qword [fSt0]
fstp   qword [fSt1]
```

In other words, we break the `FIDIV` instruction apart into separate `FILD` (integer load) and `FDIVP` (divide-and-pop) instructions. This improves overlapping, and thus shaves off a couple of clock cycles from the execution speed of the code. (On newer CPUs, from AMD Family 15h [Bulldozer] and Intel Pentium II and later—there's no real advantage to breaking up `FIDIV` into `FILD`+`FDIV`; either way you write it should be equally performant.)

Of course, since everything you have here is a *constant*, and `tan(pi/4) == 1`, your code is equivalent to:

```
fld1
fld1
```

…which is what an optimizing compiler would generate. :-)

Comment: Out-of-order execution should handle `fidiv` just as efficiently as `fild` + `fdiv`.  It decodes to 2 separate uops, presumably a load+convert `fild` uop which can execute as soon as the address is known, and a `fdivp` uop that has to wait for both inputs.  (Actually, the `fild` part of `fidiv` is a micro-fused load + ALU uop, so the load part can run separately from the p05 int->float uop.)  There might be some possible gain from scheduling the load earlier, but not if you're going to put them back-to-back.  (Except for front-end benefits if a multi-uop insn there is worse e.g. for decoding)

Comment: Also, re: last bit about constants: gcc likes to avoid `fld1` because it's 2 uops on Intel CPUs since ppro (no idea why; thanks Intel.  It's also 2 clocks on P5 while `fld` is 1 clock.).  So it would probably `fld` a `1.0` constant from memory and duplicate it with `fld st(0)`.   To avoid cache misses, `fld1` / `fld st(0)` would be good.

Comment: You'd think that OOOE would handle `FIDIV` as efficiently as `FILD`+`FDIV`, but apparently it doesn't. AMD specifically recommends making this substitution in their optimization manuals (or they did the last time I read those manuals, which was long before Ryzen, but this is x87, so not exactly bleeding-edge). Agner Fog also recommends it for P5, where `FILD` can overlap but `FIDIV` cannot. And AFAIK, P6's FPU is pretty much unchanged from P5, except for latency, which has been increased, making the separation more advantageous. But this has probably changed on modern implementations, making

Comment: this stale optimization advice, but in my define, it's very difficult to know which processor you should be assuming when talking about writing x87 code! Good point about `fld1`, though. It's 2 µops (unfused) because it requires ports 0 *and* 1. No idea why, either. It would make more sense if it used a memory-read port and an execute port, but it doesn't. So using it is not really an optimization at all. I just used it because it's easier than showing an external definition of a floating-point constant, not to mention the inconsistent syntax for that among different assemblers. @Peter

Comment: P6's FPU might be similar to P5, but the out-of-order machinery that feeds it with uops is vastly different from in-order P5.  Agner Fog's numbers for AMD K7 and later show `fidiv` as 2 uops/m-ops, with timings 1 cycle worse than `fdiv`.  Maybe that optimization-manual advice was left-over from a less-sophisticated CPU like K6?  Like P5, it might not decode to internal RISC uops.

Comment: Yeah, thinking more about it, it probably was leftover from K6. Most of the really good optimization resources online *do* tend to be for these older microarchitectures, which I read long ago and managed to even remember some of their contents. Agner Fog's manuals are about all we have now for anything modern. Maybe one of us should write a book… :-)

Comment: I actually got an email several months ago from someone asking if I wanted to be part of writing a book on assembly language, because of my Stackoverflow profile.  I think I'd go insane trying to nail down enough material for a published book.  With SO answers I know I can come back and fix them if I was wrong!  Plus, I don't do well with really long writing assignments with just myself to keep me on schedule (one of the downsides of ADHD).

Comment: On the plus side, modern x86 CPUs are pretty robust performance-wise, and don't need hand-scheduled instructions.  A *lot* of the time just counting fused + unfused uops and checking for latency bottlenecks will tell you how fast a loop runs.  It's quite remarkable that such a simple model can work so well.  (And modern x86 is often said to have few performance "glass jaws".  e.g. memory barriers are about as cheap as they can be, synchronization overhead is reasonable, and there's not much that is unexpectedly horrible.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I went back and looked at the AMD manuals. They explicitly recommended using load-execute instructions for integer and floating-point operations, *except* in the case of integer floating-point instructions. This was true back in the K6 days, as Peter suggested, but remained true all the way through the Athlon days. This advice wasn't modified until AMD Family 15h (Bulldozer), which was a complete redesign of the microarchitecture, not based on any previous designs.