# Divide a float in any of the st registers by an integer constant in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

I need to divide a float in let's say st0 by an integer (in this example 2):
So know that i can achieve this by simply:

```
mov rax, 2
fild rax
fdivp st1
```

but is there a more elegant and less bulky version like (and I know the following doesn't work):

```
fidiv 2
```

:S please let me know too if it's impossible :) thanks in advance

Comment: What assembler do you use?

Comment: Note that there is no instruction `fild rax`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the x87 instructions support immediate values. What you need to do is store the constant you want to divide by in some memory location and then load it implicitly using a memory operand:

```
    fdiv DWORD PTR two      ; st0 = st0 / 2
    ...

two REAL4 2.0
```

Note that division by constants can be sped up massively by multiplying with the reciprocal instead:

```
    fmul DWORD PTR two     ; st0 = st0 * 0.5 = st0 / 2
    ...

two REAL4 0.5
```

Comment: `fscale` is pretty slow though

Comment: @harold Agner's tables confirm that! What do you suggest instead?

Comment: I can't think of anything better than multiplying by the reciprocal

Comment: @harold Which is a one cycle instruction, so probably good enough.

Comment: Note that if you are actually dividing by an integer, then you probably want to use `FIDIV`. But you are better off separating the load and the operation (i.e., `FIDIV`+`FDIV`), because this improves overlapping. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574993/fptan-example-x86/44579076#44579076